# How to show error message as tooltip instead of explain error in Ant Design?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm validating a Form Item in Antd but having some problems. Specifically, I want to show error message as tooltip (***see image 1***) instead of the explain error of Ant Form (***see image 2***) but it doesn't work as i expected.

Image 1 (this is what i expected
):

[image]

Image 2:

[image]

Here's my sample code below:

```
<Form.Item 
    name="password"
    rules={[
        {
            required: true, 
            message: <Tooltip title='Your password cannot be empty!' color="red"/>
        }
    ]}                                                                                      
>
  <Input.Password placeholder='Enter your password' />
</Form.Item>
```

Comment: was the first image present in their example case ? or this is you want as a custom error display

Comment: @ShoyebMemon Antd don't have this case but i want to make custom error like **first image**

Comment: @ALittleGirl it's a bit difficult to handle changing display error , but i implemented an example here https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-p7vjlm please check it out

Comment: @ALittleGirl my implementation didn't help ?

Comment: @SaeedShamloo It's help for me but I'm looking for another way to clean code, I think `getFieldError()` will be useful in this case but i don't know how to implement

Comment: @SaeedShamloo Can you help me answer this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70815579/how-to-get-error-message-by-getfielderror-in-antd-form

Comment: @ALittleGirl sure, let me check.