# How to get error message by getFieldError in AntD Form?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm validating form with Ant Design but I have a problem with `getFieldError()`. I need to get the error messages by the field name of Form.Item but it not works.

Here's my code not works below:

```
...
<Form form={form} name="login_form" onFinish={onFinish} scrollToFirstError>

  <Form.Item
    label="Password"
    name="password"
    rules={[
      {
        required: true,
        message: 'Password cannot be empty!',
      },
    ]}
    help='' // hide validating message.
  >
    <>
     {({ getFieldError }) => console.log(getFieldError('password'))}
     //it not logging anything when submit form trigger error

     <Input.Password placeholder="Enter your password" />
    </>
  </Form.Item>

 </Form>
```

How can I solved this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `console.log` will invoke, every time your component renders, so you need to rerender your component whenever validation applies on the form. To handle this situation you can use render prop with `Form` component, like this:

```
function CustomFormItem({ error, ...other }) {
  console.log(error)
  return <Input.Password placeholder="Enter your password" {...other} />;
}

function MyForm() {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();
  const onFinish = (values) => {
    console.log(values);
  };

  return (
      <Form
        form={form}
        name="login_form"
        onFinish={onFinish}
        scrollToFirstError
      >
        {(values,formInstance) => {
          return (
            <>
              <Form.Item
                label="Password"
                name="password"
                rules={[
                  {
                    required: true,
                    message: 'Password cannot be empty!',
                  },
                ]}
                help="" // hide validating message.
              >
                <CustomFormItem error={formInstance.getFieldError('password')} />
              </Form.Item>
              <Form.Item>
                <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
                  Submit
                </Button>
              </Form.Item>
            </>
          );
        }}
      </Form>
  );
}
```

Consider that with above implementation, render prop will call with every change on the form.

Comment: thank you for your help, it works fine! 

Comment: What are differences between your way and my way?  My way: `<Form.Item noStyle shouldUpdate={true}> {
    ({ getFieldError }) => {
     console.log(getFieldError('password'));

     <Form.Item name="password" rules={[ { required: true, message: 'Password required!' } ]}>
      <Input />
     </Form.Item>
    }
 }
</Form.Item>`

Comment: We can also use render props `getFieldError()` inside Form.Item with `shouldUpdate` prop. What are different between both way?

Comment: @ALittleGirl in the way you added in the comment,  you have missed `return` keyword in your render porp. you need to add `return` keyword before nested `Form.Item` like this: `return (<Form.Item name="password" ...></Form.Item>)`

Comment: but in the way you have used in the question, you are using `name` property alongside with render prop, when you use `Form.Item` with `name` attribute, `Antd` expects to receive an element as children and it will add some props to the chilren of `Form.Item`, as you can see in the answer, I've just pass `error` prop to `CustomFormItem` but in the body of this component, I've received some addtional props, which `Antd` will pass to this component.

Comment: The way you have used in the comment is better way, but my answer was based on your question, in the question you have used outer `Form.item` with `name` attribute, and I thought you need to use `From.Item` with the exact structure in the question, so I tried to create a custom form element and use it with render prop of `Form` component .

Comment: i appreciate your enthusiasm. thanks once again!

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Hi @SaeedShamloo, have their any option to make it dynamically eg. i have five form field so for that scenario i have to create 5 times CustomFormItem..so if their is any solution please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

Use can use `getFieldError();` like the code example below

Function as Child Component is not working perfectly inside `<Form.Item>` component as of now.

```js
 <Form {...layout} form={form} name="control-hooks" onFinish={onFinish}>
      {(values, formInstance) => {
        console.log(formInstance.getFieldError("password")[0]);
        return (
          <>
            <Form.Item
              name="password"
              label="Password"
              rules={[
                {
                  required: true
                }
              ]}
            >
              <Input />
            </Form.Item>
          </>
        );
      }}
    </Form>
```

Comment: thank you for your help, it works fine! :)

Comment: We can also use render props `getFieldError()` inside Form.Item with `shouldUpdate` prop. What are different between both way?

Comment: Yes, we can use that method as well, Function as Child Component inside `<Form.Item>`  will only update when provided `shouldUpdate` field has changed and can receive `field update` using `form instance method` like `getFieldError()` this method is a bit optimized way but I found this method not working perfectly, as it renders 
`<Form.Item>` component, not in expected ways. - @ALittleGirl